# Error with wix/Detox on run detox build -c android

Tags: react-native, detox

I have this configurations to running Detox:

app/build.gradle
[image]

app/build.gradle tag dependences
[image]

build.gradle
[image]

build.gradle repositories
[image]

and the command fail, returned this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app/build.gradle tag dependences has two declarations "androidTestImplementation"